# How can only content be translated, not admin pages

Tags: i18n-l10n

The last developer on our site installed the entire Spanish translation from Drupal and now even the admin pages come out in Spanish.

We don't want this, we just want the content to be translated as well as some error messages, but none of the administration pages should be in Spanish.

How would I fix this?

Comment: found the answer, use administration language module